# Bootstrap visibility utility is hiding an element when it shouldn't

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to hide "Updated: " on smaller screen sizes and only keep the date - which works fine. The problem is, it hides the date and only shows the "Updated: " part in the `span` on larger screen sizes.

```css
.u-date-box {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
      bottom: 5%;
      left: 0;
      height: 2rem;
      background: #FFF;
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="u-date-box">
      <p>
        <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Updated: </span>
        <%= @post.updated_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %>
      </p>
    </div>
```

I know `d-none d-sm-block` is the issue as I tried removing those classes from the span and everything displayed fine. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works perfectly, When you are in a larger screen both updated and time will appear, and on the small screen, only time will appear. To make it inline change your `d-sm-block` to `d-sm-inline`. It will work

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div>
  <p>
    <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Updated: </span>
   abcd
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Block was making the span fill the entire length of space. I was even trying inline lists but that wasn't overriding it. Thanks for catching this, I didn't even know it was an option.

Comment: As bootstrap has some  inbuilt classes with `!important`, so you can't override that . In your case `class="d-sm-block"` displays `display:block!important`. which takes 100% of the width

Answer (score 0):

only for correct understanding:
the span:updated should disappear at smaller sizes but visible on larger screen.
the "date" should be visible at all.
Then your given code should work.

```
<div>
  <p>
    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Updated: </span>
    <%= @post.updated_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y') %>
 </p>
</div>
```

[I have added a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z34hxq69/)

Comment: Thanks but that just hides both of them on smaller screen sizes.

Comment: yes thats right. Then I guess I missunderstood your question.

Comment: Sorry, I added what I meant at the end of the second sentence.

Comment: sounds strange. I have set up a fiddle for you and you can see, the "date" is visible on all sizes.

Comment: I find it strange too, I was setting up a fiddle for the question but found the same thing.

Comment: Okay, the problem is that I had "overflow: hidden" applied to the css. My new problem is why is it overflowing and not just remaining inline?